# display nested json object when key is unknown

Tags: json, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have the following output from my API:

```
{
        "id": 82,
        "shortname": "testing2",
        "fullname": "test2",
        "address": "addrtest2",
        "telephone": "380979379993",
        "website": "www.site2.com",
        "sociallinks": {
            "facebook": "fb2.com"
        },
        "foundationyear": "1992",
        "rating": 0.0
    }
```

Now what I am trying to do is to show the socilal network column in my material table. Here is my template:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="route.navigate(['/addbuildcompany'])">Добавить</button>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> id </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="shortname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Короткое название </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.shortname}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="fullname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Полное название </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fullname}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Адрес </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="telephone">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Телефон </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.telephone}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="website">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Сайт </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.website}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="sociallinks">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Соц.сети </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element.sociallinks['facebook']}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="foundationyear">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Год основания </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.foundationyear}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Рейтинг ЕРЗ </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rating}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Действие </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="route.navigate(['/regions/'+element.id])">Детали</button> </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

When I try to show the social networks column adding a facebook key explicitly it works fine. But instead of facebook there might be any value of that key. How can I show a key name and it's value?

Here is my model class:

```
export class Buildcompany {
id?:any;
shortname?:string;
fullname?:string;
address?:string;
telephone?:string;
website?:string;
sociallinks?:string;

foundationyear?:string;
rating?:number;
}
```

And my component class:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Buildcompany} from "../../models/buildcompany.model";
import {BuildcompanyService} from "../../services/buildcompany.service";
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {MatSort} from "@angular/material/sort";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Region} from "../../models/region.model";
import {RegionService} from "../../services/region.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buildcompanies-list',
  templateUrl: './buildcompanies-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buildcompanies-list.component.css']
})
export class BuildcompaniesListComponent implements OnInit {
  buildcompanies?: Buildcompany[];
  currentBuildcompany: Buildcompany = {};
  currentIndex = -1;
  shortname= '';
  fullname='';
  address='';
  telephone='';
  website='';
  sociallinks='';
  foundationyear='';
  rating='';
  public displayedColumns = ['id','shortname','fullname','address','telephone','website','sociallinks','foundationyear','rating','action' ];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Region>();
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true})
  sort: MatSort = new MatSort;
  constructor(private buildcompanyService: BuildcompanyService,public route:Router) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveBuildcompanies();

  }
  retrieveBuildcompanies(): void {
    this.buildcompanyService.getAll()
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          // this.regions = data;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

          this.dataSource.data=data;

          console.log(data);
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }
  refreshList(): void {
    this.retrieveBuildcompanies();
    this.currentBuildcompany = {};
    this.currentIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems what you need to use is an 'index signature'. Currently TS doesn't know which key will be used.  A usage like [key: string]: string should fix your problem.  This post can be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584145/how-to-get-data-from-nested-data-in-rest-countries-api-v3/70598537#70598537

Comment: did you try keyvalue pipe

Comment: Now working on it but have no idea how to put it in a row of material table.

Comment: Plus the problem is that only nested array is those social links. All others are static

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you all ho helped me. Short story before. This is my second project on angular and first task like I described in a question. I tryed to use the key value pipe but then started to implement it using *ngfor got an error from my IDE that this comand cannot be resolved. So I just put it as a div element and all worked just perfectly.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of element.sociallinks | keyvalue">
        {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
      </div>
```

Now the question is: is loop in Angular works only within an html element only? But I gues it could be an other topic

Comment: Use update to edit your initial comment if you find any answer to your initial question. In this situation you are adding also new questions. Please make sure they are relevant to the initial question this thread is created about.